# Dev versioning multiple branch

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins

I am trying to get the develop branch and the xyz ticket branch (not main) to increment the version off of each other.so if I merge a PR into develop and it build version 1.1.5 then when I merge a PR into tickets, I want it to build version 1.1.6 via jenkins

I need the do via jenkins.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I can’t give the best answer, we would be happy to get more information about your request. As far as I understand you want to use one brach version, to another and increment it automatically. Could be achieved in a few ways, but you should get it from 3rd party environment. Some text/version control such gitlab for instance and have a specific repo that you mange configuration/text files that you can write to it or read from it, as well to increment it but pushing back to this git repository. Less optional is having it in some local share storage and manage it the same. Another way to achieve this is add to the name of a branch at first repo the version itself, then in Jenkins you can checkout branch names from other repositories and pass it, so at the second repo you could get it from the first repo branch name, you can define it.